# How do I create an Apdex score in Librato?

Tags: librato

Say I have a series of request timings and and I want to score them and I have 2 thresholds, 4s and 12s. A request completed in 4s or less gets +1, between 4s and 12s gets +0, and over 12s gets -1. I want to sum up the scores and then divide them by the total count of the timings. How can I do this in Librato?

Answer (score 4):

Currently Librato doesn't offer an Apdex score, but there are ways to get an overview of the request timings.

One simple method would be to build a [composite metric](https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/data_processing/composite_metrics/index.html) using the map() function. This would allow you to break out your metrics request time by host, and visualize the request rate per minute:

```
map({source:"*"},
  rate(s("query-api.rails.request.time", "&", { period: "60", function: "sum" }))
)
```

If you are wanting a [Big Number](https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/visualize/big_number.html) chart that provides a general idea of the overall request times (as the Apdex score provides) then you could use the following composite metric to display the percentage of hosts reporting under 400 ms:

```
scale(
  divide([
  sum(
      map({source:"*"},
          divide([
              filter(s("query-api.rails.request.time", "&", { period:"60", function:"mean" }), {lt: "400", function: "mean"}),
              filter(s("query-api.rails.request.time", "&", { period:"60", function:"mean" }), {lt: "400", function: "mean"})
          ])
      )
  ),
  sum(
      map({source:"*"},
          divide([
              s("query-api.rails.request.time", "&", { period:"60", function:"mean" }),
              s("query-api.rails.request.time", "&", { period:"60", function:"mean" })
          ])
      )
  )
]),
{factor:"100"})
```

Both of these examples utilize the metric `query-api.rails.request.time` which comes from [librato-rails](https://github.com/librato/librato-rails), but you could substitute this metric with any metric that reports the request time (eg. the front-end collector [librato-client](https://github.com/luk3thomas/librato-client)).